# Jquery token input get data from function as array

Tags: jquery, input, token

I am using the excellent token input jquery plugin, however I cant seem to make it source its data from a simple function call which returns an array.

My scenario is I am using it within sharepoint as embedded html/script, and I have no control over the sharepoint environment, meaning I cannot add a server side page to return data via ajax.  I have instead a generic javascript function which returns data as an array.

From my research it is not possible to point token-input to string/array data, and when attempting it and stepping into the code the data source is always treated as a url.  Has anyone managed to discover a way to make token-input use a simple string/array as a data source?

thanks in advance